# How do I get the value of a custom field in HTML format in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a Wordpress plugin called "[easy content types](http://pippinsplugins.com/easy-content-types/)" which provides a rich text editor to help you add HTML format textarea in to the custom field. I want to display the content in my template page.

Usually I use `get_post_meta($post->ID, "my_field", true)` to get a custom field meta value. But in this case, it does not work. Seems get nothing.

I can display the value use `<php? the_meta(); ?>` in my template. But I have no idea how to display this specific field use `get_post_meta( )` or other Wordpress functions.

The "easy content types" plugin provides a method `<php? ecpt_display_meta('meatbox');?>` to get the value also.  But it can only get the value of a group of fields, that's not what I want actually.

I've searched in google for answers, but can't find related questions. So hope some one can help me. Thanks!

Comment: I I don't know why... but now I found <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "my_field", true);?> works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about..

```
<?php 
$myfield = get_post_meta($post->ID, "my_field", $single = true);
echo $myfield;
?>
```

just have a check and make sure the custom field your trying to access is using the same name.

Marty

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why... but now I found <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "my_field", true);?> also works.

Comment: That's because it does exactly the same thing, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

If your custom field is a multiline text, you can echo that like this to be in HTML format:

```
<?php
$customfield_content=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'customfield-name',true);
$customfield_content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $customfield_content );
$customfield_content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $customfield_content );
echo $customfield_content;
?>
```

Or use the way described in this [website](https://paper-leaf.com/blog/2014/06/formatted-content-custom-field-wordpress-get_post_meta/)